# CollectionView-Simple sample code

Tags: iphone, ios6, xcode4.5, uicollectionview

Used CollectionView-Simple sample code from apple. when run their project it works. But when run my project which is exactly same as apple sample code it doesn't shows images with grid layout but shows only navigation bar.  Any idea why it is so.

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: Check your dataSource and delegate for the UICollectionView

Answer (score 1):

Check your dataSource and delegate for the UICollectionView in IB and make sure they are set just like the sample. More than likely you forgot to assign the delegate and dataSource to the UICollectionView.

Answer (score 1):

### Data Source and Delegate

You need to make sure that the collection view's `dataSource` and `delegate` are set properly.

If you are using Interface Builder, then make sure that you right-click drag* from the collection view to the little orange blob at the bottom of the scene. Repeat twice, once for both the Data Source and the Delegate.

If you are creating the view in code, you just need to say

```
self.cview.delegate = self;
self.cview.dataSource = self;
```

<sub>* AKA control-click</sub>

Comment: using storyboard and in connection inspector section it is already showing that outlets as datasource view controller-collection view and delegate view controller -collection view